# Why does Flutter Image Cropper plugin Crash upon First Build Only?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm using the `Flutter Image Cropper` plugin. The first time I build the app and try to crop an image, the app crashes when I click to save the cropped image. But if I rebuild the app, it works perfectly. I think this may be related to permissions as I had a very similar problem with audio record permissions. This was solved by using the `Permissions Plugin` to request all permissions at the top of the app.

The permissions I am requesting in my AndroidManifest.xml file are;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I've also added this to the AndroidManifest.xml;

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
  />
```

Here's the method I'm using to check permissions at the top of my widget tree;

```
    Map<Permission, PermissionState> permission = await PermissionsPlugin 
       .checkPermissions([
  Permission.CAMERA,
  Permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
  Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
  Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
  ]);
```

Although the `Permissions Plugin` managed to solve the crashing of my app upon first build, it doesn't seem to have helped with the `Flutter Image Cropper` plugin.

Can anyone see what's going on?